# Collapsible text under title

Tags: html, collapsable

I am trying to make a text collapsible when I press the word 'Abstract' in my webpage, https://rubencioak.github.io/research.html, I thought the following code was going to be enough:

```
<ol class="lead">

<li> <p> <b>Free-riding in Collective Agreements,a Search and Matching Model of Minimum Wages</b> 
<br />  

<span id="abstract-link" class="abstract-click">Abstract</span>
<p class="abstract-text" style="display:none; font-size:.90em">Does free riding in collective... unemployment, at a cost of employed earning less</p>

</p> </li> </ol>
```

I am using a templeate from HTML5 and also looking at this webpage: https://messertodd.github.io/research.html. for reference.

Now, although I thought it was basically the same, something is obviously wrong with this code.

All in all, the question is: is there a simple way to make my text under the word abstrac collapsible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

KR

Comment: That code is not enough. where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: Sorry, I am just very new at this html thingy, you are completelly right and gave me the hint to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) and [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) tags:

```html
    <details>
        <summary>Abstract</summary>
        <p class="abstract-text" style="font-size:.90em">Does free riding in collective... unemployment, at a cost of employed earning less</p>
    </details>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally solve the problem, nonetheless this workaround worked perfectly.